# How to refresh table data efficient way

Tags: sql, database

I have few analytics table which gets refreshed in every few days. By refresh I mean there could be some new records, some records needs to be deleted and some records needs to be updated and there is no specific identifier.

So there are below options in my mind:

1. For every refresh truncate the whole table and reload data. But if any failure occur during fresh data load then table data will be corrupted and all analytics will show wrong data.
2. Another option is to keep a refresh id in all analytics table, and while reading data from analytics table use latest refresh id. But with this approach main issue is joining and filtering. We have joining across analytics table so each and every join should join with refresh is always otherwise fetched data will be wrong, and this approach is error-prone.
3. Can We create a view on these table which will have dynamic filter ? While querying on these views I will use latest refresh id as a filter.

Is there any better approach to refresh data into analytics tables keeping in mind that it should handle any error scenario and not error prone.

Answer (score 1):

Or, the option that I often use:

1. Create a new version of the table in an alternative location.
2. Validate the results.
3. Swap the live table for the new version.

The "swap" might involve renaming tables or truncating and loading the original table.  Often, the original contents are saved somewhere else.

This approach is handy particularly when the logic for creating the entire table is complicated to express as incremental changes.  It also minimizes the amount of downtime, when the table is not available.

You want incremental changes when you need more up-to-date data and batches don't work -- either because of timing, size, or cost.  Many databases support materialized views or replication which simplify this process.